# How to create a session using jsoup and how to post the data using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I can't create a session using **jsoup** and how to post the data using `jsoup`. Please help me, I'm new to `jsoup api`, actually my code is:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://wiki.my---------------")
    .userAgent("Mozila")
    .timeout(0)
    .method(Method.GET)
    .execute();

Document docu = res.parse();
Map<String, String> cookies = afterLogin.cookies();
Document doc2 = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://wiki.my------------------")
    .data("os_username", "A57", "os_password", "pass")
    .data("login", "Log on")
    .cookies(cookies)
    .timeout(0)
    .post();
```

I get one webpage (*doc2*)and then add to some table to that webpage (*doc2*)?

How to add new data already existing web page *doc2* and then how to post *doc2* to anther `url`. Already tried a lot, please help me.

Comment: What is `afterLogin`?

Comment: it is res.cookies() ,not afterLogin.cookies()

Answer (score 10):

For using jsoup to login to any website and retrieving and Parse the data from this website, you just need to follow the bellow instructions:

First point you need to know what is the name of cookies ( Session Name) that you will use it to login to all pages of site.

NOTE: you can know the Session Name of any website as bellow:
Login to your website that you want to know the Session Name or cookies for it
Then write in URL field this command

```
javascript:void(alert(document.cookie))
```

copy the session name then do this

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("login Site URL")
            .method(Method.GET)
            .timeout(10000)
            .execute();

   String sessionID = res.cookie("SESSION ID for site");//here put the Session Name for website
```

now you have the Session Name of website but still you need to fill it with your login info

```
String username="your username";
String password="your pass";

Jsoup.connect("login Site URL")
            .data("login:username", username, "login:password", password, "login:loginImg", "", "login", "login")
            .cookie("SESSIONID", sessionID)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .timeout(10000)
            .execute();// now you have filled the Session Name with your login info and you can use it for any page in website


Document doc = Jsoup.connect("any page of site")
            .cookie("SESSIONID", sessionID)
            .timeout(10000)
            .get();// her to open any page with Session
```

Name that you already have it

now you just need to go to the tag or element that you need to get your data from it

```
System.out.println(doc.body().text());// for print all text in page
```

or if you have element ID you can get data like this

```
String S = doc.select("span[id^=here put element id]");
System.out.println(S);
```

or like this

```
String S=doc.getElementById("ElementID").text();
System.out.println(S);
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great answer! I just found a way to optimise it
`.cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID)`
could become
`.cookies(res.cookies())`
this way it just sets all of them

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are using wrong cookies, try this

```
Document doc2 = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://wiki.myatos.net/display/RMSTRV/CCBO+Patches")
    .data("os_username", "A57", "os_password", "pass")
    .data("login", "Log on")
    .cookies(res.cookies())
    .timeout(0)
    .post();
```